# Backup Database - error in SQL Syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, backup

Estou construindo um botão para fazer um Backup do meu `db`via aplicação `C#`,
está tudo correndo bem, porém na hora de aplicar o ExecuteNonQuery está acusando erro de `syntax`.

Segue:

Designar Path:

```
    private void Browser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
            FazerBackup.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Fazer Backup:

```
    private void FazerBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       MySqlConnection conexao = ClassConexao.ObterConexao();

        try
        {


            string data = conexao.Database.ToString();

            string cmd = "backup database [" + data + "] to disk='" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";



            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, conexao))
            {
                if (conexao.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conexao.Open();
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexao.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sucesso");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Check the fields {0}", error.Message));
            return;
        }
    }
```

Conexão ja está aberta e o caminho(Path) ja está no box.

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ps: Mesmo direto no *MySql - SQL Editor* esta syntax não está funcionando; estranho, pois todo tutorial que vejo, está exatamente igual.

Comment: Tem como postar o comando gerado?

Comment: Como assim @LINQ ? este é todo meu comando, unica coisa que faço antes é abrir a conexão e designar o path dentro do textBox.

Comment: O SQL gerado, jovem.

Comment: O valor da variável `cmd`.

Comment: cmd = "backup database [" + data + "] to disk='" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

Comment: O valor, jovem, o **valor**, em tempo de execução. O comando SQL gerado.

Comment: "backup database [eaglemotors] to disk='C:\\Backup\\database-2017-08-23--13-40-37.bak'"

Comment: Isso é pra ser MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: MySql @LINQ.....

Comment: Isso é um statement do SQL Server, não do MySQL.

Comment: Putz ! @LINQ que mancada heim.
enfim, obrigado por indentificar o erro então, vou buscar a do MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo a minha própria pergunta:

O Erro na verdade está no comando que é para SQLServer e não para MySQL.

segue o comando para MYSQL:

```
    private void FazerBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string conn = "server=HostDoSeuServer; database=SuaDataBase; Uid=SeiUser; pwd=SuaSenha";


        //String para gravar o Path Designado por um Browser:
        string file = textBox1.Text + "\\database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + "-.sql";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    mb.ExportToFile(file);
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Sucesso!");
                }
            }
        }


    }
```